# Magent2.3.4 Optional Input is converted to Required after add new validation rule on checkout page

Tags: validation, input, magento2, option-type, required

I have created a new validation rule.

```
app/code/Vagwan/MotoValidation/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

    var config = {
        config: {
            mixins: {
                'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                    'Vagwan_MotoValidation/js/validation-ui-mixin': true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

JS script

```
app/code/Vagwan/MotoValidation/view/frontend/web/js/validation-ui-mixin.js

    define([
        'jquery',
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        return function (validator) {

            validator.addRule(
                'mobilePL',
                function(value) {
                    return value.length > 9 && value.match(/^((0|\+44)7\d{3}\s?\d{6})$/);
                },
                $.mage.__('Please specify a valid mobile number')
            );

            return validator;
        };
    });
```

And enabled validation rule in custom checkout:

```
app/code/Vagwan/CustomCheckout/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

        $vatId = [
            'component' => 'Vagwan_CustomCheckout/js/view/form/element/vat_id',
            'sortOrder' => 61,
            'label' => __('NIP'),
            'dataScope' => 'billingAddress.vat_id',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'billingAddress',
                'template' => 'Vagwan_CustomCheckout/form/element/vat_id',
            ],
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => false,
                'mobilePL' => true
            ],
            'required' => 0,
        ];
```

Original Magento2 rule

```
app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js

        "mobileUK": [
            function(value) {
                return value.length > 9 && value.match(/^((0|\+44)7\d{3}\s?\d{6})$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please specify a valid mobile number')
        ],
```

It is very weird, because when I am using default validation rule called mobileUK the input is optional, when I use my custom validation rule mobilePL then inpust is changed to required input. mobilePL and mobileUK has same JS script inside. One is custom antother is stnadard magento2 rule. How can I avoid this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if value is empty. If empty than return true

```
define([
  'jquery',
  './utils',
], function ($, utils) {
  'use strict';

   return function (validator) {
     validator.addRule(
       'mobilePL': [
         function (value) {
           return utils.isEmpty(value) || value.length > 9 && value.match(/^((0|\+44)7\d{3}\s?\d{6})$/);
         },
         $.mage.__('Please specify a valid mobile number')
       ],
     }
     return validator;
   };
});
```